# ElasticSearchTestCase : while Creating client instance using ESIntegTestCase

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch, junit, integration-testing

While I am declaring @BeforeClass Notation and declare my ElasticSerach Client 
it is giving me this kind of Error.

I want `Client` Instance only one in my test Class. I am writing test case using `ESIntegTestCase` this Class.

This is my code.

```
public class PersonTest extends ESIntegTestCase {

    private static Client client;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClient() {
        client = ESIntegTestCase.client();
    }

    @Test
    public void createIndex() {
         // Using client's instance creating an index.
    }

    @Test
    public void search() {
         // Using client's instance Seach would be perform.
    }

}
```

I am getting this kind of Error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([F541A8F42426AB1C]:0)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.client(ESIntegTestCase.java:633)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.client(ESIntegTestCase.java:626)
    at com.saba.search.elasticSearch.PersonTest.setUpClient(PersonTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.invoke(RandomizedRunner.java:1713)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$6.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:847)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$7.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:863)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.AbstractBeforeAfterRule$1.evaluate(AbstractBeforeAfterRule.java:45)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleStoreClassName$1.evaluate(TestRuleStoreClassName.java:41)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule$1.evaluate(NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule.java:40)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule$1.evaluate(NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule.java:40)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleAssertionsRequired$1.evaluate(TestRuleAssertionsRequired.java:53)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleMarkFailure$1.evaluate(TestRuleMarkFailure.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures.java:64)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreTestSuites$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreTestSuites.java:54)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl$StatementRunner.run(ThreadLeakControl.java:367)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it happens because a test cluster is not initialized yet. There is no need to have the client variable static. I'd propose to use @Before annotation and instance variable

Comment: Cluster is initialized in `ESIntegTestCase.beforeClass()` that annotated also with `@BeforeClass`. There is no warranty that it will be called before your method. But it is public so you could try to call it yourself. Note that `prepareCreate, ensureGreen or refresh` methods of class ESIntegTestCase are not static.